# Using Qt CSS to set own Q_PROPERTY(QFont)

Tags: qt, qt4

I'm using Qt 4.6.2 and i have problem with QCSS. I have own Q_PROPERTY(QFont myFont READ myFont SET setMyFont). I want to change it with QCSS but it doesn't work. I've tried using normal `font` syntax but it doesn't work. I've also tried few other combinations like:

`qproperty-myFont:`
`font(serif 20 1 0)`
`font(serif 20 bold)`
`QFont(serif 20 1 0)`
`QFont(serif 20 bold)`
`QFont(bold 20px serif)`

etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, after longer research i found methods `QFont::toString` and `QFont::fromString`. It's not so clean and "css nice style" but it works now:

`qproperty-myFont: "serif,-1,14,5,0,0,0,0,0,0";`

Where parameters are: font family, pointSizeF, pixelSize, `QFont::StyleHint`, `QFont::Weight`, `QFont::Style`, underline, strikeOut, fixedPitch, rawMode

Comment: A note: often (i.e. when there's only one font used) you can get away with using the QWidget's `font` property, which is supported in stylesheets with that nice syntax.